# Seg fault in C on weight[a]= data;

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, ansi-c

```
fscanf(ifile, "%c", &jnk);
/* If there's a height, this will be a ". if not, it'll be a ,*/
if ((jnk = '\"') || (jnk != ',')) {
    printf("%c", jnk);
    while(fscanf(ifile, "%c", &data) && data != ',' && data != '\"' && data != '\'') {
        printf(" %c ", data);
        weight[a]= data;
        a++;
    }
    weight[a] = '\0';
    player[n].weight=atof(weight);
    printf("%.0f ", player[n].weight);
} else if(data == ' ' || data == ',') {
    player[n].weight= 0;
    printf("%.0f ", player[n].weight);
}
```

GDB tells me storing data into weight give me the seg fault. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Could you please try and reformat that so that it's not all on one line? Please [edit] your question to do so. (And look at the preview before submitting.)

Comment: Can this question be more elaborated ? it would be interesting to know what is datatype for jnk

Comment: Where is `a` declared? Is it initialised to zero? What does the declaration for `weight` look like? We need to see more of the code to determine where the problem is.

Comment: `(jnk = '\"') ` It is probably a mistake.

Comment: impossible to diagnose without a complete program

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

i hope you assign `"` and `,` to a. And when you use `weight[a]`, you get an error since the ASCII value of the character is taken, which may be out of bounds of the array size that you have declared

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is either here

```
fscanf(ifile, "%c", &data)
```

or

```
 printf(" %c ", data);
```

Depending on the datatype of data, there is something wrong in the way you are interpreting this variable, and also depends on what is the initial values of different variables you've defined.